# is there a point to wearing armour in star wars

Tags: star-wars

when anyone actually hits an armoured target in star wars e.g; the average stormtrooper, the armour serves no protection against any form of laser fire. this would lead me to believe the armour is used to protect against less advanced races who more likely wield swords and shields however in the return of the Jedi the stormtrooper's armour does nothing to protect against the Ewoks and their rocks.following my previous logic I assume that the armour is resistant against certain weapons/materials, however, I'm not versed in the star wars universe, so does armour serve any purpose in the star wars universe other than aesthetics?

Answer (score -2):

I would say its more than aesthetic.

[Armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Armor)

Their armor an equipment are suited to the function of the soldier.

Take for example the variations of the stormtrooper:

The [snowtrooper](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Snowtrooper) adjusted to  cold climates.
The [scout](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Scout_trooper), with more lightened armor to perform quicker moves.

And there are many more [variations](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Stormtrooper_(First_Order)) such as [Phasma](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Phasma) from ep 7, or the ones with [jetpack](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Imperial_jumptrooper) (I don't remember if this have any movie source but there are games in which they appear).

I will edit my answer if I find the video where a stormtropper reciebes 2 shots, being the first one absorved by the armor.

I think its from Ep 6, in the moon fight.

Leaving the stormtroopers aside, you can consider other tipes of armor, like a [cortosis armor](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Cortosis-weave_armor) to disable lightsabers

Comment: This reads mostly as opinion and conjecture. It would be good to edit this to reflect the value of armour referenced in sources (e.g. environmental protection with snowtroopers as an example).